# Rails is there a way to collect all routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am using this as an example:
https://github.com/toshimaru/Rails-4-Twitter-Clone

The route file looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions,      only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :tweets,        only: [:index, :create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  get    'signup'   => 'users#new'
  get    'signin'   => 'sessions#new'
  delete 'signout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  get    'about'    => 'static_pages#about'

  match '*path' => 'application#routing_error', via: :all
end
```

It appears that in some controllers there are comments mentioning which route it uses, however it's not specified in the route file. For instance:

```
 # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  def show
    @tweet = current_user.tweets.build if signed_in?
    @feed_items = @user.tweets.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

(in `users_controller.rb`)

My question is, how does rails app know that there is an endpoint here? I would like to know whether I can actually collect all the routes in one file?

What I am intending to do is, I would like to replace current `routes.rb` file with all routes.

Comment: So based on the comments you've made on some of the answers,  you don't want to examine the routes,  you want to replace them? With what? Do you want to dynamically create routes?  You need to clarify your question, maybe give an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, no definitely not. All I want to do is replace the current routing with something that is more understandable, that's why I thought if I collect all the routes, I'd be able to use them all. However it doesn't seem to be possible due to `resources`.

Comment: `resources` is just a short-cut way of specifying routes. `resources :users` automatically creates `index` ("/users") and `show` ("/users/:id") and `edit` ("/users/:id/edit") and `new` ("/users/new") and the post/put/delete routes that match to `user#create` and `user#update` and `user#destroy`. If you prefer to list them individually you can do that, but that's not very clever since `resources :users` does it for you automatically.

Comment: You should review http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html and you'll understand that `resources` makes things easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

`resources :users` has automatically created all RESTful routes for you, although you can limit it to only certain routes (as your example does with sessions, tweets, and relationships).

You can see all the routes from the console... in the root of your project do `rake routes`

See here for an explanation...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#listing-existing-routes

You can access the output of `rake routes` in your application....

```
output = `rake routes`
```

(note the use of backticks in the above)

Comment: Thank you very much, but `rake routes` does not print out an output where I can simply replace the content of `routes.rb` file.

Answer (score 2):

Its specified in route file

When, we write

```
resources :users
```

It creates [CRUD](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) routes for specified resource namely index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy routes for resource, here in this case resource is `user`. 
You can see all routes for user by

```
rake routes | grep 'users'
```

and to list all routes in application

```
rake routes
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but `rake routes` does not print out an output where I can simply replace the content of `routes.rb` file.